# How to check if file was selected with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to find out why this won't work.

photoVal always equals nothing. So the background I have never disappears. When I select a file shouldn't the value change?

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.browsebutton').bind("click" , function () {
        $('#uploadphoto').click();
   });

var photoVal = $('#uploadphoto').val();

    $('#uploadphoto').change(function(){
        alert(photoVal);
    });

    if (photoVal !== ''){
        $('#photo').css('background', 'none');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="photo">
     <img id="preview" src="#" alt="Image Preview" />
</div>
<br>
<div id="browse">
     <button type="button" class="browsebutton">Add Photo</button>
</div>
<input type="file" id="uploadphoto" name="uploadphoto" style="display: none;"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems like a duplicate.

Try this :

```
$(function() {
     $("#uploadphoto").change(function (){
       var file_name = $(this).val();
     });
  });
```

Comment: Works thanks, it was a duplicate but mine wasn't working and I couldn't figure out why.